# Gnome Terminal won't start on Fedora 28

Tags: linux, terminal, fedora, gnome

I recently updated to Fedora 28, and now `gnome-terminal` won't start anymore:

```
[bf@localhost ~]$ gnome-terminal 
# Locale not supported by C library.
        Using the fallback 'C' locale.
# Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Failed to activate service 'org.gnome.Terminal': timed out (service_start_timeout=120000ms)
```

On searching the internet, it is supposed to do something with the locale, but that looks OK:

```
[bf@localhost ~]$ localectl
   System Locale: LANG=en_GB.utf8
                  LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
                  LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
                  LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
                  LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
                  LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: us
      X11 Layout: us
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue here for Brazilian Portuguese, first tried installing glibc-langpack-br as suggested in some forums (in your case glibc-langpack-uk I believe) but that alone didn't solved the problem here, I've solved it by installing langpacks-pt_BR, which is a meta-package that should install the missing pieces for my language, you may try:

```
sudo dnf install langpacks-en_GB
```

Comment: Now my locale is set to `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`, and there is no langpack for that.

Comment: I fiddled with the locale, and with langpacks and it works now.